# Creating a phone software lock Application for android

Tags: android

I need to create an Application that can lock the handset at some specific Event.

either i want to make use of Require Pattern programatically.

or create a lock application, just like windows mobile in which there are digits to be entered instead of a Pattern.

please guide me to the path if creating this application is possible.

Answer (score 5):

There is no supported way to create such an application. Users can always press the HOME key, for example.

Comment: Couldn't you catch the keyevent for the home button press?

Comment: Applications do not receive the HOME button press.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like part of the question was whether you could require the pattern lock programmatically.

The DevicePolicyManager (present from Android 2.2 onwards) should allow you to enforce the pattern lock:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html

Think question provides a little more detail:
[Locking an android phone (lock pattern or similar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935006/locking-an-android-phone-lock-pattern-or-similar)