# Locking an android phone (lock pattern or similar)

Tags: android, locking, design-patterns

Since LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED was moved to Settings.Secure in Froyo my app can no longer lock the screen...

Does anyone know a workaround for this? Any way that my app can instantly lock the screen? No matter if its the autolock pattern or some kind of custom lock screen...

Answer (score 4):

This is a little cumbersome...

If you add a `DeviceAdminReceiver` to your app and the user enables it the security settings then you are allowd to call

```
DevicePolicyManager dpm = 
    (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
dpm.lockNow();
```

to lock the device immediately.

If you don't have a  `DeviceAdminReceiver` in your app the call to `.lock()` will cause a `SecurityException`.

Comment: there's a little more to it than just implementing a DeviceAdminReceiver. see the device administration docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html