# unable to lock device through device administration api

Tags: android, device-admin

i want to set 2 minutes of user inactivity that can occur before the device locks using [setMaximumTimeToLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setMaximumTimeToLock%28android.content.ComponentName,%20long%29).

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample;
...
long timeMs = 1000*60*2;
mDPM.setMaximumTimeToLock(mDeviceAdminSample, timeMs);
```

but the above code is not working. please tell the suitable one.

thanks.

Comment: What does the logcat say ? Are you testing this on Android 2.2 or above ? Is your app a device admin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you implemented a DeviceAdminReceiver?

This answer says it is necessary:
[Locking an android phone (lock pattern or similar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935006/locking-an-android-phone-lock-pattern-or-similar/4833101#4833101)